# Iretarting over column & creating min() column for each of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have dataframe as below

```
d = {'Name':['Alisa','Bobby','jodha','jack','raghu','Cathrine',
'Alisa','Bobby','kumar','Alisa','Alex','Cathrine'],
'Age':[26,24,23,22,23,24,26,24,22,23,24,24],
'Score':[85,63,55,74,31,77,85,63,42,62,89,77]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['Name','Age','Score'])
Name    Age     Score
0   Alisa   26  85
1   Bobby   24  63
2   jodha   23  55
3   jack    22  74
4   raghu   23  31
5   Cathrine    24  77
6   Alisa   26  85
7   Bobby   24  63
8   kumar   22  42
9   Alisa   23  62
10  Alex    24  89
11  Cathrine    24  77
```

When i run the code below, it works fine & gets the output as shown. A new column for each for the column.

```
a=df.columns[1:]
df[a +'rat'] = df[a]/df[a].sum()
Name    Age     Score   Agerat  Scorerat
0   Alisa   26  85  0.091228    0.105853
1   Bobby   24  63  0.084211    0.078456
2   jodha   23  55  0.080702    0.068493
3   jack    22  74  0.077193    0.092154
4   raghu   23  31  0.080702    0.038605
5   Cathrine    24  77  0.084211    0.095890
6   Alisa   26  85  0.091228    0.105853
7   Bobby   24  63  0.084211    0.078456
8   kumar   22  42  0.077193    0.052304
9   Alisa   23  62  0.080702    0.077210
10  Alex    24  89  0.084211    0.110834
11  Cathrine    24  77  0.084211    0.095890
```

However, when i want to create a `Min` for each of the columns with the code a below, i get the error `"KeyError: "None of [Index(['Agemin', 'Scoremin'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`.  I wanted it create that column!

```
df[a +'min'] = df[a].min()
```

so, how do we go about creating `min()`, `max()`, `sum()` etc columns for each of the columns without having to specify the names of each of the columns?

Comment: `min` aggregates to one value per column. You are then trying to set the entire column with this value. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: If I do `df['min'] = df['Age'].min()`, I get a new column with minimum filled throughout. I want that for all the columns without having to specify names of each of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `assign` multiple scalar values from a Series using `**` to pass the arguments. The index becomes the column name, with the value broadcast to all rows. For a Series `add_suffix` adds to the index, while later I use it to add to column names, which how that behaves for DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df.select_dtypes('number')

df = df.assign(**df1.min().add_suffix('min'))
#        Name  Age  Score  Agemin  Scoremin
#0      Alisa   26     85      22        31
#1      Bobby   24     63      22        31
#2      jodha   23     55      22        31
...
#10      Alex   24     89      22        31
#11  Cathrine   24     77      22        31
```

Personally, I would `concat` the other result:

```
df = pd.concat([df, (df1/df1.sum()).add_suffix('rat')], axis=1)

#        Name  Age  Score  Agemin  Scoremin    Agerat  Scorerat
#0      Alisa   26     85      22        31  0.091228  0.105853
#1      Bobby   24     63      22        31  0.084211  0.078456
#2      jodha   23     55      22        31  0.080702  0.068493
#...
#10      Alex   24     89      22        31  0.084211  0.110834
#11  Cathrine   24     77      22        31  0.084211  0.095890
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. For me, doing the calculation in a seperate dataframe & concatenating it again seems cumbersome. But thanks to your answer, i figured out a solution `df.assign(**df.iloc[:,1:].min().add_suffix('min'))` !!! With this i can directly create new columns within the dataframe :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you would prefer to do it using your original code, you can do:

```
df[a +'min'] = df[a].groupby(by=np.zeros_like(df.index)).transform(min)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works as well. However, since i can only accept i answer, i am going with the one from AL0llz because that seems to be faster (1.23 ms vs 6.43 ms) and he answered quickly.

Comment: Sure, no worries. Happy to see you've got multiple solutions you can choose from.